# realiza backup en MS ACCESS [ delphi]

Tags: ms-access, delphi

Necesito realizar una copia de seguridad para mi aplicaron en delphi,estoy trabajando con ADO y MS access.
Entiendo que mi pregunta no es puntal ya que no tengo progreso de lo que estoy comentando.

Comment: Pablo, además de lo que comentas en tu pregunta, hay comentarios en otras preguntas tuyas dónde se piden aclaraciones, que no obtienen respuesta de tu parte. Eso reduce las posibilidades que encuentres ayuda en futuras preguntas.

Comment: con respecto a a la pregunta anterior de las fechas  opte por dejarlo como estaba por otra parte la pregunta actual como dije no es una pregunta adecuada pero también me vendrían bien unas recomendaciones de como poder hacerlo  para ir resolver el problema.

Comment: pablo, si _optaste por dejarlo así_, quizás lo correcto es que elimines tu pregunta, o bien que la continúes por el simple hecho de aprender. Sobre esta otra pregunta, me parece bien si no tienes ningún avance, que busques ayuda para aclararte, pero en ese caso, asegúrate de incluir más información. No es lo mismo, por poner un ejemplo, si hay un solo usuario conectado a la base de datos, que si varios _clientes_ atacan un mismo archivo. Así, seguro hay otros detalles que son necesarios para responder la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Access es una Base de Datos de escritorio, no depende de ningún servidor para funcionar. Toda la Base de Datos está contenido en un único fichero, sea un **MDB** para las versiones antiguas o un **ACCDB** para las nuevas.

Para realizar una copia de seguridad de la Base de Datos, basta con realizar una copia del fichero utilizando las funciones de windows ([CopyFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile)) o en tu caso desde Delphi puedes utilizar `CopyFile` que es la función "puente" para acceder a la API y que se encuentra en la unit `Winapi.Windows`.
La única precaución sería la de que no exista nadie conectado a la Base de Datos ya que en ese caso puedes obtener un error al no poder acceder al fichero por estar en uso.

Comment: Gracias Germán también quería preguntar si existe alguna función para restaurar  base de datos MS Access.

Comment: Hola, @Pablo, creo que lo correcto es que esta segunda pregunta (diferente a la original) la formules creando una nueva. Porque si hay respuesta correcta alguien que busque el mismo problema no lo encontrará segun el título actual. Son cosas diferentes (aunque relacionadas). Revisa este link antes de formular la nueva poregunta, te ayudará: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask